# Dojo: How to send a POST request with dojo.io.iframe.send

Tags: javascript, post, iframe, dojo

I am unable to send a POST request with dojo.io.iframe.send. According to the documentation (http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dojo.io.iframe.send and http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/io/iframe), you are supposed to be able to send a parameter method: 'POST' and have it post the request. But that isn't happening.

I created a JSFiddle to show the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/Ayyoudy/J67hT/2/

Watch the network traffic with Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug and you'll see that it always uses GET instead of POST

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer incase it helps someone else. You basically have to create a form and set the form method to post and assign it to the dojo.io.iframe.send form parameter...

Don't understand why, but doing that changes the request into a POST one!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code for the form and dojo.io.iframe.send parameter? I'm not quite sure by reading this, if the form needs to be around the button or just on the page.  Thanks!